# Apache Rewrite: show files from two directories in the same directory

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I need to access files from two directories in the same directory in a browser.

Visually the directories may look like this:

**/public_html/www.example.com/xml/**

**/xml/**

**/public_html/.htaccess**

Important clarification: this setup supports multiple domains.

**/public_html/www.example1.com/**

**/public_html/www.example2.com/**

The XML files requested at **http://www.example.com/xml/** are located at **/public_html/www.example.com/xml/** and if the file does not exist at that server path then I need to check at the **/xml/** server path.

Obviously from the browser we'll be accessing the **/public_html/xml/** path (e.g. **www.example.com/xml/**) so let's say we can see a directory index with Apache generated links to all the XML files. I want to be able to also access the files in the **/xml/** directory from **example.com/xml/**.

There is also the issue of files having the exact name being present in both directories. I'd prefer the **/public_html/xml/** directory to take precedence so if a user requests **www.example.com/xml/1.xml**  the copy at **/public_html/xml/1.xml** is displayed instead of **/xml/1.xml** if possible.

Remember, I want to MERGE access to all the files in both directories to a single directory, I do not want to make files from either directory inaccessible in order to make the files in other directory accessible.

This must be done using the .htaccess file located at **/.htaccess** beneath.

Comment: @John-  Did u work out any solution for this problem?

Comment: @Hacker I don't believe I ended up doing what I asked here some 9 years ago, I'm certainly not doing it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like that .htaccess in /public_html/xml/

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$  -  [L]

RewriteCond /PhysicalPath2AnotherFolder/%{REQUEST_URI}  -f [OR]
RewriteCond /PhysicalPath2AnotherFolder/%{REQUEST_URI}  -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /WebPath2AnotherFolder/$1  [L]
```

ps: PhysicalPath2AnotherFolder should have, but not include, webpath of the original directory in it. Or, of course, it is possible to add additional RewriteCond in order to take only the filename from REQUEST_URI. In that case it would be something like (I did not test it :))..

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/.*?([^\/]+)$
RewriteCond /PhysicalPath2AnotherFolder/%1  -f [OR]
RewriteCond /PhysicalPath2AnotherFolder/%1  -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /WebPath2AnotherFolder/$1  [L]
```

Comment: Will look at it and try it out in just a bit and let you know what the results are; thanks for posting!

Comment: @John      Sorry, I'm not going to try anything at 4 am ) I'm going to sleep, but if nobody corrects me in 8 hours, I'll try it by myself :) Btw, you should understand that it will not give an index of both folders. php script might generate a listing from both.

Comment: I didn't ask you to try anything, I was simply acknowledging your post and that after I finished taking care of some RL stuff that I would try it out which I'm going to do now.

Comment: @John Ok, I've checked and made a small correction. It is working :) And sorry for misunderstanding - I really wanted to sleep.

Comment: coolbeans, thanks! My turn to go to sleep, been up 26 hours. I will try this out tomorrow morning and let you know how it goes, thanks for your help!

Comment: No success, I think I need to make a few clarifications. The root most path in Apache is public_html/, with multi-domain support each website has it's own DEDICATED folder (e.g. public_html/www.example.com/). The SYSTEM files are in example in public_html/xml/ while the website's override files are in public_html/www.example.com/xml/. Localhost I can access public_html however live each domain IS the root of course (local / test, live/not test). I don't understand what physicalpath equates to, system or site specific xml folder?

Comment: @John Hm.. I thought that I wrote comment to you :) If your folders are on different domains then mod_rewrite will not help you. Unless the second folder is `mounted` on another domain's folder by symbolic link, which can be followed by Apache, or with alias directive of the Apache server.

Comment: The .htaccess file is on the same host account, it's merely different www folders in the same directory as the .htaccess file.

Comment: @John  Are they both available from the domain name (together with the folder where you want to put .htaccess file)? Both "merging" directories should be available through the URL at the same site.

Comment: This setup supports multiple domains, example1.com, example2.com. The core files (e.g. xml/) are shared by ALL domains while www.example1.com/xml/ xml files are ONLY available to THAT given domain. What I'm trying to do is provide FALL-BACK "system" copies for each domain. The root (/ which is public_html/ in the file system) is NOT actually a domain itself EXCEPT for localhost on my local production computer; live it's not accessible ANYWHERE so that root xml/ folder is merged to all domains. Make sense? All domains use own dedicated databases/CSS but XHTML code is the same.